# Is there a built in SharePoint object which lets you know if you are in a form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, form, branding, jsom

I'm in the process of branding a SP-tenant using JS-injection and CSS. I've been able to use `ctx` and `_spPageContextInfo` in many cases, but in some cases they aren't initialized.

What is the best way to find out what type of page I'm on?

At the moment I need to figure out if I'm in a edit/new/display form. Also, if anyone knows which JS file holds the `ctx` and `_spPageContextInfo` that would be a great help. I have to executeordelay on those files later. For now I'm trying my scripts in the console as a proof of concept.

Edit: I'm on SharePoint online / O365.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath.contains("DispForm.aspx"))
// View form
if (_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath.contains("EditForm.aspx"))
//Edit form
if (_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath.contains("NewForm.aspx"))
//New form
```

You can try replacing contains with `endsWith()`, it should work better.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded("SP.js", function() {
// use context or _spPageContextInfo here
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. But we have many different forms. For now I do a check on a element id, like this: if (document.getElementById("onetIDListForm")) { code... }